# Why is the question "Certain sound is played after last if within script" on hold?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This is my question: [Certain sound is played after last if within script](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/74171/certain-sound-is-played-after-last-if-within-script)

Did I asked an off-topic question? Does this include off-topic content? Maybe wrong reason to close it? If so, what is the actual reason the question is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says right in the hold description why your question was put on hold:

> Questions about debugging a problem in your project must present a
>   concise selection of code and context so as to allow a reader to
>   diagnose the issue without needing to read all of your code or to
>   engage in extensive back-and-forth dialog. For more information, see
>   [this meta thread](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/what-counts-as-a-debug-my-code-type-of-question).

Fundamentally your question is asking us to *debug your code* for you, a process which often involves an extensive back-and-forth discussion and which is unlikely to ever be useful to future visitors. It's not what this site is for.