# How is my question regarding FBX off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

How do people benefit from narrowing the list of acceptable topics, why are "superusers" forcing topics on hold or closing them. What is this site all about, is it information warfare, downgrading topics that don't seem relevant to you. Whats not relevant to one person may be an extremely important topic to someone else, and people should strive to help each and not discourage one another from our goals.

My [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/97503/how-to-i-correctly-load-fbx-scene-in-a-d3d-application) was about an FBX problem and that's clearly related to game programming and better suited to this forum than any other and there seems to be very limited number of topics on this forum regarding it, can people vote to save my topic from being binned please..

Comment: Are you talking about [this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/97503/how-to-i-correctly-load-fbx-scene-in-a-d3d-application)?

Comment: yes that one, its been driving me crazy for weeks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case your question appeared to be what the community generally considers a ["debug my code"](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/what-counts-as-a-debug-my-code-type-of-question) question, and off-topic. The reason is that is provides only a vague problem description "it conflicts with FBX somehow," and some limited diagnostics output (indication that some DLL you are -- likely indirectly -- causing to load could not be found). This tends to mean we can only make educated guesses. Further, this type of question is generally only useful to the individual asker and consequently runs against the general principles of StackExchange (to provide a useful database of questions and their best-possible answers that is useful to everybody).

For those reasons, the community regards that kind of question as off-topic and you'd be better off asking it at an actual discussion forum, like [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net).

Comment: thanks Pete, that answer is good enough for me, ill continuing seeking a solution myself